# Running Scrapy-Splash through vpn

Tags: python, scrapy, vpn, scrapy-splash

I am attempting to run a scraper using Scrapy-Splash through my university's VPN as it is required to gain access to the pages that I want to scrape. However, when I attempt to crawl the pages while my VPN is connected, Scrapy-Splash doesn't work. I have tried it without the VPN and the script runs fine. How do I sold this problem? This is my error:

```
2021-06-27 16:56:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-06-27 16:56:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.mergentarchives.com/searchResults.php?searchType=annualReports&companyName=3Com+Corp.&compNumber=37958&aracompNumber=0/searchResults.php?searchType=annualReports&companyName=3Com+Corp.&compNumber=37958&aracompNumber=0 via http://0.0.0.0:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.>]
```